# How do you prevent LESS partials from compiling on their own?

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

I use LESS partials, which are includes (@include) into the master LESS stylesheet. There's no reason each partial needs to compile to it's own css file, but it does, cluttering up the project. 
In SASS, if you start the file with an underscore, it recognises it's only a partil so doesn't compile it. But LESS doesn't do the same. Is there a recognised way to name a LESS partial?

I'm using PHPStorm to compile the LESS.

Comment: LESS can compile whatever file you will provide. It's PhpStorm (and your settings) that compile every file separately. So .. what functionality do you use to compile your .less files? I assume it's File Watchers ... or is it dedicated LESS plugin? Screenshots with settings please.

Answer (score 2):

You can add "LESS profiles" from `Settings` dialog. `LESS profiles` let you setup `Source directory` etc. and also `Exclude files by path`.